# Delete item from Array with nested items

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to delete item from an array with nested items. Here's the array,

```
{
  "name": "Main Course",
  "items": [
    {
      "menuname": "Chinese",
      "id": "12",
      "menu": [
        {"name": "Noodles",id="1"},
        {"name": "Rice",id="2"},
        {"name": "Xinjiang Roast",id="3"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "menuname": "Indian",
      "id": "14",
      "menu": [
        {"name": "Rice",id="2"},
        {"name": "Paratha",id="5"},
        {"name": "Dal Fry",id="6"}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to delete the item say, {"name": "Rice",id="2"}, from the first menu (menuname:Chinese). Please note that the same item appears in another menu (menuname:Indian) too, which I don't want to delete. Looks like the common approach is to find the indexOf the item to delete and splice it. Here's what I tried,

```
myArray[0].items.forEach(function (val) {
        if((val.menuname==="Chinese" && val.id==="12"))
          {
            val.menu.forEach(function (value) { 
              if(value.name === "Rice" && value.id==="2"){

                myArray.indexOf(value.name);
              }
            })
          }

        });
```

This always returns an index of -1. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:A close vote for unclear question (Seriously?). The code I am using doesn't return the proper index and I asked what is wrong with the code. With all due respect, please spend some time reading the question.

Comment: use splice in removing array elements
refer: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_splice.htm

Comment: Is `id="3"` JSON format?

Comment: @Fractaliste, The array is what I get after running JSON.stringify on an object.

Comment: @Semi-Friends Yes, I mentioned about splice in my question too. My problem is I am not able to get the proper indexof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your JSON string look strange.

Then you can't call `myArray[0]` because you don't get an array:

```
var k = {
    "name": "Main Course",
        "items": [{
        "menuname": "Chinese",
            "id": "12",
            "menu": [{
            "name": "Noodles",
                "id": "1"
        }, {
            "name": "Rice",
                "id": "2"
        }, {
            "name": "Xinjiang Roast",
                "id": "3"
        }]
    }, {
        "menuname": "Indian",
            "id": "14",
            "menu": [{
            "name": "Rice",
                "id": "2"
        }, {
            "name": "Paratha",
                "id": "5"
        }, {
            "name": "Dal Fry",
                "id": "6"
        }]
    }]
};

k.items.forEach(function (val) {
    if (val.menuname === "Chinese" && val.id === "12") {
        for (var i = 0; i < val.menu.length; i++) {
            if (val.menu[i].name === "Rice" && val.menu[i].id === "2") {
                val.menu.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
});

console.log(k);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XmsQR/2/

Comment: What's the best way to delete the items? I can delete individual items  with delete value.name or delete value.id but that leaves an empty {} in the array.